# maximum weight on a directed graph (weighted)

Tags: graph-theory

I have a problem in finding an algorithm for matching of maximum weight on a directed graph (weighted). In particular, I would also need to find all the matching induced by subgraphs of the given graph. Searching the literature I found the algorithm Edmnond but has the disadvantage of making all the calculations again for each subgraph. is possible to have an algorithm that stores some previous steps in order to optimize the whole? Or do you have other ideas as well as the algorithm of Edmond? thanks